# Should I apply to another company while waiting for an interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, applications

I applied to Company A (a company I really like) a few months ago, but the Managing Director (MD) of Company A told me at that time that there were no available job openings and there may be some available this Jan/Feb 2017. She really liked me (I think) and said that she would instead give me a referral to Company B (they're competitors of Company A, though she has a good relationship with the Managing Director of Company B) just in case I wanted to send my resume to that Company.

Fast forward to the present - I tried keeping in touch with Company A, contacting them recently (to tell them I'm still very interested to join their organisation) and asked if there's any update on their vacancies. She said that she would love to meet me for coffee next week. Though I'm not sure what the topic of the conversation will be - it might be that they have job openings already, or not and will just tell me to just pursue other companies (such as Company B). I haven't tried sending my resume yet to Company B though I'm planning to.

My question is: Should I send my resume to Company B now, even before meeting Company A next week or should I wait for Company A to meet me and send my resume to Company B afterwards?

Comment: Questions asking for **advice on what to do are not [practical answerable questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)** (e.g. *"what job should I take?"*, or *"what skills should I learn?"*). Questions should get answers explaining *why* and *how* to make a decision, not advice on what to do. For more information, click [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this question will be closed as per [Draken](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/52713/draken)'s comment, but for what it's worth I would definitely send my resume to Company B before meeting again with Company A (and would have done this as soon as practically possible after the initial meeting with Company A.

Your contact at Company A has tried to help you out (as far as we know!) by referring you to a competitor in the same field, offering to vouch for you to some extent by the sounds of it, which is not something she had to do. For you to then pass up on this opportunity to make contact with Company B and seek a job with them could quite possibly make your contact at Company A think you are not actually motivated to get a job (which could lessen her inclination to help you get one), that you are not appreciative of her time and assistance (which could damage your relationship with her and any future opportunities it could bring) and other negative things which are unlikely to help you.

You don't state **why** you haven't sent your resume to Company B since your original meeting with Company A though, perhaps you have a legitimate reason (you don't want to work for Company B, or you're willing to pass up on any chance of working there to ensure you're free for Company A if they find a position for you to apply for), but if it's just because you didn't get round to it, or didn't think about it in the intervening months, that makes you look bad in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment above - it is very helpful. Actually I haven't sent my resume yet to Company B because I went on few months of leave and flew out of the country because of personal reasons so temporarily stopped job searching. Now, you're right - I want to ensure I'm free for Company A if they find a position for me in the future.

Comment: Then I think you've answered your own question - if you want to be free for Company A should the opportunity arise to work for them, then it seems sensible to hold off sending anything to Company B until your upcoming coffee chat with your contact at Company A. If there is still no progress on a position for you to apply for at Company A, then you can re-assess whether you wish to apply to Company B.

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I send my resume already to Company B even before meeting
>   Company A next week or should I wait for Company A to meet me and
>   afterwards send my resume to Company B?

Since the person you are meeting has offered to give you a referral instead to Company B, first meet and see what is said.

Then send your resume to Company B.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well - that I'll try this last chance of asking again and if it won't turn good then I will go then go to Company B.